# Implement dynamic class with closure in C# like in this Python code

Tags: c#, python, csv, closures

I'm would like to read a tab separated file where the first line is the header.
The goal of this implementation is to not waste memory and time to create a dictionary for every line while trying to have this indexing work: `line[column_name]`
This is my Python implementation:

```
def readf(filename):
    for i, line in enumerate(open(filename)):
        cols = line.strip().split('\t')
        if i==0:
            class Line:
                _header = {col: i for i, col in enumerate(cols)}
                def __init__(self, data):
                    self.data = data
                def __getitem__(self, key):
                    return self.data[self._header[key]]
        else:
            yield Line(cols)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ll = []
    for line in readf("hello.tsv"):
        ll.append(line["col1"])
```

Can this be implemented in a similar fashion in C#?
I'm new to C# and from what I searched so far it doesn't support defining a class in a function.
Closures in C# don't seem to have useful resources on the web.
Thanks

**Edit:**
The previous implementation takes 3.3s, the following one takes 4s for a 1GB file with about 1M lines

```
from itertools import izip

def readf(filename):
    header = []
    for i, line in enumerate(open(filename)):
        cols = line.strip().split('\t')
        if i==0:
            header = list(cols)
        else:
            yield {header:cols for header,cols in izip(header, cols)}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ll = []
    for line in readf("hello.tsv"):
        ll.append(line["col1"])
```

Comment: This seems to be an X-Y problem, reading a tab-separated file in C# shouldn't "waste" memory. What are you trying to do with the data, read it all into memory and then index it?

Comment: make a Hashset of a certain group of columns

Comment: Is there a reason it must output a class?  Or will a simple key-value pair output work?

Comment: no reason to output a class, i would just like the convenience of being able to index by any header column, without creating a Dictionary for every line in c#

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to create a dictionary? That's the perfect data structure for this.

Comment: I think it would be faster to not create a Dictionary for every line. Just somehow have a wrapper for every line so that it behaves like a Dictionary. And have just the header line as a Dictionary

Comment: Have you tried with dictionaries already?  I don't know why it would be slow to create a dictionary for every line.  I mean your way would work too. But you'd have to create an Dictionary that defines key-to-ordinal position. I would make sure a Dictionary collection doesn't work first for what you're looking for. No reason to optimize for something that doesn't need to be optimized :)

Comment: I had an implementation with Dictionary running on linqpad, it ran in about 14 seconds on the same data. I'll try in visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the discussion, a couple ways to accomplish this:

List of Dictionaries:

```
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> aLines = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        var aFile = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        var aColumns = aFile.First().Split('\t');
        aFile.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(line =>
        {
            var aSplitLine = line.Split('\t');
            Dictionary<string, string> aDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < aSplitLine.Length; i++)
            {
                aDictionary.Add(aColumns[i], aSplitLine[i]);
            }
            aLines.Add(aDictionary);
        });

        int row = 0;
        string fieldValueExample = aLines[row]["field_Value"];
```

or by creating an ordinal look up:

```
        var aFile = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        int anIndex = 0;
        var aColumns = aFile.First().Split('\t').ToDictionary(field => field,field => anIndex++);
        var aFileData = aFile.Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToList();

        var row = 0;
        string fieldValueExample = aFileData[row][aColumns["field_Value"]];
```

I haven't looked at the compiled output, but I assume the second one is technically faster at the expense of readability due to fewer operations performing during the import.  Though, when reading field values, the trade off might be that you are looking at two indexes to arrive at the field value.

At the end of the day, I'd be reluctant to pre-optimize like this.  Do what is readable and maintainable by you and who will be assisting you first and see if that accomplishes the task.  In most environments, nobody is going to notice something running a couple seconds longer.

Or.. alternately, if you are trying to get interoperability with .Net (vs. a requirement to port to C#), you could always just use Iron Python.

http://ironpython.net/

Comment: I did a similar implementation and takes about 5 seconds, good enogh. Thanks!

Comment: although c# has evolved the blogpost is mostly still true 9 years later http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-learning-haskell-python-makes-you-a-worse-programmer/

Comment: Python and C# share a lot of similarities in their design philosophy.  There is a lot more functional programming in the most recent versions of the C# syntax.  That's undoubtedly owed to the influence of other languages such as Python, Ruby and Haskell.  The "object oriented" concepts of Python objects, with a few exceptions, actually port to C# pretty well.